# Open Layout window on a second monitor

Tags: windows

Is it possible in Blender to open a completely different window and place it on a second monitor? The same way we can open a shading or uv window and split the screen, but to have that shading window placed on a different monitor. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold down the **Shift** key and then drag from the top right hand corner of the 3D viewport
as if you were wanting to split the screen, this will result in opening a smaller floating window of the 3D viewport which you can then drag to your second monitor and then set full screen.

Or Open the **Window menu** at the top left and choose the **New Window** option.

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Daniel You can mark the answer as accepted **✓** if it solved your problem :).